# Need to have the manifest generated data moved deeper inside of the jar

Tags: java, maven-2, manifest

Due to a design issue outside of my control, the `MANIFEST.MF` file populated by the Maven Archiver plugin (inside of Maven jar plugin) is overwritten.

Can I:

1. move the file further down into the jar (i.e. from `/META-INF` to `/src/home` or something)
2. Populate a different file with the contents that would normally go into `MANIFEST.mf` (i.e. `src/home/something.txt`)

I've tried to change the `<manifestFile>` property but that just merges the manifest from that location to the `/META-INF` location.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't say explicitly, but I assume you want to move the file using maven, i.e. as part of the build?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes I use Maven as part of a Hudson build process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the point - that's not a `MANIFEST.MF` anymore - but if you move the contents to, say `src/main/resources/src/home/something.txt`, `src/home/something.txt` will end up in the jar. Unless I misunderstood something, this is what you asked for. If it isn't, please clarify.

Comment: I would actually just call it MANIFEST.MF(I didn't to clarify that the information inside the file was what i cared about)- my desire is to get the manifest information and put it in somewhere else that doesn't get overwritten-so I can use it to view the build information on the server it is eventually deployed to.

If I could create a file called something.txt inside the jar with the exact contents of the MANIFEST.MF file- I would be happy.

Comment: @rickjr82: So you still want it to get generated, that's it? If yes, when does the generated MANIFEST.MF get overwritten exactly? That may be important for an alternative answer.

Comment: It gets overwritten after it gets deployed to the server. I don't have access to this server and the deploy is a standalone process which takes the jar as an input.

I do want it generated, I need the data.

Comment: I know I need to know how to move the contents of the manifest file, my question was how.

Comment: I just unjar, copy, rejar - not the most ellegant solution, but it works

Comment: @rickjr82: Erf, I misread one of your comment. I read *"I don't want it generated"* and I didn't suggest to unjar/rejar. Sorry for that.